# Prototyping in Java instead of extending

Tags: java, javascript, prototype-programming

Is Javascript-like prototyping anyhow achievable, even using Reflection? Can I wrap my object inside another one, just to extend its functionality with one or two more methods, without wiring all its original nonprivate methods to the wrapper class, or `extends` is all I get?

Comment: i think you could `extend` the class or maybe wrap it in a [Decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)

Comment: You can use dynamic proxy API (`java.lang.reflect.Proxy`) or libraries like `cglib` that will help to accomplish what are you trying to do. But in all cases it will not be so easy as in `JavaScript`. Reflection in `Java` is always a big pain especially when you used to prototype-programming world!

Comment: I think you can put those in an answer.

Comment: I'm talking about an instance of `java.awt.Component` obtained via invoking `getParent()` of a `Label`. I need to override one of its methods. I don't want to create a subclass of Component just because of this.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for extension methods, you could try Xtend. Xtend is language that compiles to java code and eliminates boilerplate code.

The following text is stolen from the [Xtend Docs for extensions](http://www.eclipse.org/xtend/documentation.html#extensionMethods):

By adding the extension keyword to a field, a local variable or a parameter declaration, its instance methods become extension methods.

Imagine you want to have some layer specific functionality on a class Person. Let us say you are in a servlet-like class and want to persist a Person using some persistence mechanism. Let us assume Person implements a common interface Entity. You could have the following interface

```
interface EntityPersistence {
  public save(Entity e);
  public update(Entity e);
  public delete(Entity e);
}
```

And if you have obtained an instance of that type (through a factory or dependency injection or what ever) like this:

```
class MyServlet {
  extension EntityPersistence ep = Factory.get(typeof(EntityPersistence))
  ...

}
```

You are able to save, update and delete any entity like this:

```
val Person person = ...
person.save  // calls ep.save(person)
person.name = 'Horst'
person.update  // calls ep.update(person)
person.delete  // calls ep.delete(person)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this in Java. You can though in Groovy, using [metaclasses](http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN3525-MetaClasses)

```
String.metaClass.world = {
    return delegate + " world!"
}

println "Hello".world()
```